# Making a Java library that will be used in Android, one class implement Parcelable interface

Tags: java, android, client-server, parcelable, serializable

For university exercise I have to create a server that will listen to an Android application.

I have to save a object User that will be sent from Android to the server, and then the server has to store it in memory by implementing Serializable interface.

Up to there I get everything, but my model in Android uses the interface Parcalable, and Java doesnt recognize this interface.

How can I make a library for both the server and the android application, so they regocnize the object I am sending as an object from the same class User?